# Ruby on Rails: Best way to save search queries in a database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

For a RoR app I'm helping develop, I need to save all search queries in a database so I can analyze them later.

My plan right now is to create a Result model and table, and just save each search query's text in that table, along with a user's ID, the time, etc.

However, the app has about 15,000 users, so I'm afraid the single table approach won't be super efficient when it comes time to parse that data. (The database is setup via MySQL, if that factors in at all.)

Am I just being paranoid? Is there a Ruby gem that handles this sort of thing, or a better approach I could take?

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are couple of approaches you can try:
1. Enable mysql query logging and than analyze these logs 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html
2. Use key=>value store (redis comes to mind) to log the search query in a similar way you described

If you decide to go with the 2nd approach i would create an asynch observer on the model you want to track

Comment: Okay, cool. I was researching observers as well, but wasn't sure if that was the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you want to do with the data.

If your users don't need access to this, and you're not doing real-time analytics, dump them out of your app and get them into another database to run analytics to your heart's content.

If you want something integrated into your app, try a single mysql table.

Unless your server is tiny or your users are crazy active searchers, it should work just peachy. At a certain point you'll probably want to clear out old records and save them elsewhere though.

Comment: Yeah, it's strictly for the benefit of me and the other people on the team. As far as I know, it won't show up in the app anywhere. I'm just trying to do it 'right,' if you follow me. And the plan right now is to strip any saved queries older than 3 months.

Comment: In that case mysql query logging with a cron job that dumps it somewhere off your server every few days seems like the "right" approach